# Arduino class implementing TimeLib.h

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I'm creating this library for the ESP8266-Arduino that makes use of the TimeLib.h library.

In my header I have:

```
WiFiUDP *_UdpNTP = NULL;
void    setupTime();
time_t  getNtpTime();
void    sendNTPpacket(WiFiUDP *u);
```

And these are my functions:

```
void Konnec::setupTime() {
    setSyncProvider(getNtpTime);
    setSyncInterval(NTP_POL_TIME);
}


time_t Konnec::getNtpTime() {
//WiFiUDP udp;
//udp.begin(localPort);

_UdpNTP = new WiFiUDP();
_UdpNTP->begin(localPort);

while (_UdpNTP->parsePacket() > 0); // discard any previously received packets
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // 5 retries.
    sendNTPpacket(_UdpNTP);
    uint32_t beginWait = millis();
    while (millis() - beginWait < 1000) {
        if (_UdpNTP->parsePacket()) {
            Serial.println("");
            Serial.println("Receive NTP Response");
            _UdpNTP->read(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
            // Extract seconds portion.
            unsigned long highWord = word(packetBuffer[40], packetBuffer[41]);
            unsigned long lowWord = word(packetBuffer[42], packetBuffer[43]);
            unsigned long secSince1900 = highWord << 16 | lowWord;
            _UdpNTP->flush();
            return secSince1900 - 2208988800UL + TIMEZONE * SECS_PER_HOUR;
        }
        delay(10);
    }
}
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("No NTP Response :-(");
return 0; // return 0 if unable to get the time
}

void Konnec::sendNTPpacket(WiFiUDP *u) {
// Zeroise the buffer.
memset(packetBuffer, 0, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
memcpy(packetBuffer, sendBuffer, 16);

if (u->beginPacket(timeServer, 123)) {
    u->write(packetBuffer, NTP_PACKET_SIZE);
    u->endPacket();
}
}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
konnec.cpp: 991:28: error: cannot convert 'Konnec::getNtpTime' from type 'time_t (Konnec::)() {aka long int (Konnec::)()}' to type 'getExternalTime {aka long int (*)()}
   setSyncProvider(getNtpTime)
Error compiling libraries
```

Any knows what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `Konnec::getNtpTime` is a class method, and yet `setSyncProvider` expects a function. A function and a method are different things remember, as a method also needs to know the specific class instance it is operating on.

Looking through your code though, it looks like `getNtpTime` doesn't rely on anything specific to your class, so you could declare it as:

```
static time_t Konnec::getNtpTime();
```

which will let it be used as a function, as it effectively is at that point.

Comment: Valid point, Nonanon. Actually, if I make it static I cannot access the UDP class. But that method was using a single variable from my class: TIMEZONE. So what I did was make them functions (took them out of my class), and created a method in my class to modify the timezone variable (taking the value from the TIMEZONE variable from my method). That fixed it.